# Problem with Android Emulator on Android Studio. HAXM Kernel Module not Installed

Tags: windows, android-emulator, android-sdk, intel-haxm

I recently switched over from Eclipse ADT to Android Studio and as soon as I tried to fire up the emulator, I saw the following message:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

On Googling around, I found that disabling **Hyper-V** would solve this problem. It did. And the emulator worked like a charm. But then, my internet stopped working. In any form. WiFi, Ethernet, every kind of service went bust. Re enabling Hyper-V restored my internet connection, but the error came back. So, I can either use the internet or my emulator.
I really can't keep doing that. Is there an alternate to this?

Comment: Wow, 20k views in  5 months and **no** answer?

Comment: @Pacerier it's a common issue, and yet, no fix has been found. Since then, I have been using my device/genymotion for development

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Intel's HAXM module. HAXM accelerates your emulator so you don't test apps like a slideshow.

> My advice: Install Intel HAXM. Leave Virtualization Acceleration functions (Hyper-V, Vt-X etc.) activated and the emulator will work. There seems to be something wrong with your network adapter/configuration, too. Virtualization should be independant from your network.

Also please read the error message first and do a Google search to make sure such questions aren't already answered.

Comment: I did install Intel HAXM. I still have the problem. Also, I did Google the issue, but didn't find anything apart from disabling Hyper-V

Comment: The error message "HAX kernel module is not installed!" makes me assume it's not installed. If Hyper-V is not used, it shouldn't cause any issues AFAIK.

Comment: So here's what I did. I disabled Hyper-V and installed HAXM. The emulator then worked. But re enabling Hyper-V gave this error message again.

Comment: The emulator works even without HAXM. HAXM only works if Hyper-V is enabled. Else there is no Virtualization Acceleration HAXM could use. Is your processor able to hardware accelerate virtualization?

Comment: That's strange :/ For me HAXM only works when Hyper-V is disabled

Comment: Hyper-V is independent from your CPU. It's some feature by Microsoft to virtualize PCs.

Comment: Okay, let me try installing HAXM from Intel's website.

Comment: Also, this is where I got the advice from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18207178/2302611

Comment: That seems to be an issue with Windows 8. On my Win7 machine it's working alright.

Comment: Oh. What would be a possible solution then?

Comment: Seriously, I have no idea. On my PC everything works fine with Hyper-V, HAXM and Vt-X enabled. The ARM emulator works in real time so it must be an issue with some network management software that relies on Hyper-V (very strange though).

Comment: Well, in that case, I'll keep this question open. :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a new Virtual Device in AVD Manager with API level above 14.   Try using API level 15 or higher.